# Statistical Tests for data with some repeated measures

Tags: mixed-model, chi-squared-test, repeated-measures

I have some data with a binary outcome and a categorical predictor. I would like to perform something like a chi-square test to test for associations, but some of my data is repeated. I am not interested in change over time, I just would like to use all the data. Is there a form of mixed model analysis I can use to do this?

Comment: what data is repeated ?  pl. give a sample of repeat data

Comment: glmer of the lme4 package in r may be interesting for you... You can copy the output of dput(your_data) to your question, to get better answers.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what data has been collected and what hypotheses you are testing? In particular, what is being repeated and why isn't everything repeated? The first few lines of your data table would be useful to visualise the data.